# Split values in brackets using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string that looks something like - 
" [value1]\n[value2]\n[value3]\n[value4]\n"
or like:
" [value1]\n[value2]\n[value3]\n[value4]"

I'm trying to get a list of all my values in brackets:
value1, value2, value3, value4

My research showed me to use Regex, but I'm not getting any matches.

Can anybody help?

Here's a sample of what I tried:

Regex.Matches(myText, "[(.*?)]")

Comment: As in the question linked: `Regex.Matches(myText, @"\[(.*?)\]")`. Or `@"\[([^][]*)]"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: less than 30 seconds, impressive.

Comment: I already saw that question - but that answer does not work for me

Comment: @SOS: It [is working well](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%5b(.*%3f)%5c%5d&i=+%5bvalue1%5d%0d%0a%5bvalue2%5d%0d%0a%5bvalue3%5d%0d%0a%5bvalue4%5d%0d%0a).

Comment: YOur second answer works for me. Thanks.

Comment: Just as a proof - http://ideone.com/qvRyX4. If your content is not the one you provided in the question, it makes the question an XY problem. `(.*?)` would work, too, if you pass the `RegexOptions.Singleline` flag (as I guess you have a newline inside the `value`s).